# Find 5 largest numbers in array of objects and push it to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects and I want to find the five biggest numbers in object values and to push these five objects to the new array, but also remove them from the first array. I've tried using for loop combined with push and splice methods, but the result is kind of weird.
Here is an example of what I've tried

```js
const arrOfObjs = [
    {number: 1, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 2, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 3, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 9, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 4, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 10, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 5, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 6, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 7, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 8, bla: 'sadsad'},
]

let largestNumbers = [];

for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  largestNumbers.push(
    arrOfObjs.splice(
      arrOfObjs.indexOf(
        Math.max.apply(
          Math,arrOfObjs.map(function(o){
            return o.number;
          })
        )
      ), 1)[0])
}

console.log(largestNumbers)
```

Everything seems to be working instead of the final result, which should be

```
[{
  bla: "sadsad",
  number: 8
 }, {
  bla: "sadsad",
  number: 7
 }, {
  bla: "sadsad",
  number: 6
 }, {
  bla: "sadsad",
  number: 9
 }, {
  bla: "sadsad",
  number: 10
}]
```

I'm not sure why number 9 isn't returned, and why the number 5 is. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about sorting first and then slicing?

Comment: `arrOfObjs.sort((a, b) => b.number - a.number).slice(0, 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do `.indexOf` on an array with objects using an integer as the parameter.

Try `.findIndex(({number})=>number === Math.max.apply ...`

```js
const arrOfObjs = [
  {number: 1, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 2, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 3, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 9, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 4, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 10, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 5, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 6, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 7, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 8, bla: 'sadsad'},
]
let largestNumbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  largestNumbers.push(
    arrOfObjs.splice(
      arrOfObjs.findIndex(({
          number
        }) => number ===
        Math.max.apply(
          Math, arrOfObjs.map(function(o) {
            return o.number;
          })
        )
      ), 1)[0])
}

console.log(largestNumbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `indexOf` part. You will not find the maximum value, because your array has objects (with `number` property that should be compared instead). So replace

```
arrOfObjs.indexOf(Math.max ........)
```

with:

```
arrOfObjs.findIndex(o => o.number === max)
```

... where `max` is the `Math.max` expression, which you should then do separately, like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   let max = Math.max.apply(
      Math,
      arrOfObjs.map(o => o.number)
   );
   largestNumbers.push(arrOfObjs.splice(
      arrOfObjs.findIndex(o => o.number === max), 1)[0]
   );
}
```

Comment: Please consider this answer, moving the `Math.max` calculation out of the `findIndex` callback, as you don't want to repeat the very same call over and over again as in the accepted answer... It makes it very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would sort it and then slice it.

```js
const arrOfObjs = [
    {number: 1, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 2, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 3, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 9, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 4, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 10, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 5, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 6, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 7, bla: 'sadsad'},
  {number: 8, bla: 'sadsad'},
]

console.log(arrOfObjs.sort((a,b)=> a.number - b.number).slice(-5))
```